# How to run dependent scripts in python in parallel in shell?

Tags: python-3.x, shell

I have 6 scripts called:

```
A_1.py, B_1.py, C_1.py
A_2.py, B_2.py, C_2.py
```

How do I run these script with the following dependent logic where C scripts should be run (in parallel) on B is complete while at the same time running A and B scripts in sequential order in shell?

[image]

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: When you have complex dependencies, and some programs could run in parallel, I would concider to use a simple Makefile and run the entire program with `make -j4` or someting like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless I have misunderstood your table, it is no harder than this:

```
A_1.py   # Start A_1
B_1.py   # then B_1

# We can now start A_2 followed by B_2, along with C_1 in parallel    
{ A_2.py ; B_2.py; } &
C_1.py &

# Now wait for all of those to complete, and start C_2
wait
C_2.py
```

Comment: Thank you, this works wonderfully. The only question I have is how would I manipulate the parallel execution portion if I wanted to run not only C_1 but also run C3 and C4 in that exact sequence in parallel with A2 and B2? Could you help please?

Comment: Questions, and answers, are free. Just ask another one, and you’ll get better attention from the whole Stack community.

Comment: Just change `C_1.py` to `{ C_1.py; C_3.py; C_4.py; } &`

Answer (score 0):

I've never done this before, but I believe makefiles are the way forward:

A Makefile consists of a set of rules. A rule generally looks like this:

```
targets : prerequisities
   command
   command
   command
```

The `targets` are file names, separated by spaces. Typically, there is only one per rule.
The commands are a series of steps typically used to make the target(s). These need to start with a tab character, not spaces. The prerequisites are also file names, separated by spaces. These files need to exist before the commands for the target are run.

So let's assume you want to run 5 commands: `cmd1`, `cmd2`, `cmd3`, `cmd4`, `cmd5`. Assume the following dependencies:

- `cmd1` and `cmd3` have no dependencies
- `cmd2` depends on output from `cmd1` and `cmd4`
- `cmd4` depends on the output of `cmd1`
- `cmd5` depends on output of `cmd4` and `cmd3`.

In this case, the Makefile would look like:

```
all: cmd1.run cmd2.run cmd3.run cmd4.run cmd5.run

cmd1.run : 
   cmd1
   touch cmd1.run

cmd2.run : cmd1.run cmd4.run
   cmd2
   touch cmd2.run

cmd3.run :
   cmd3
   touch cmd3.run

cmd4.run : cmd1.run
   cmd4
   touch cmd4.run

cmd5.run : cmd3.run cmd4.run
   cmd5
   touch cmd5.run
```

Now you can just run your scripts with the simple command:

```
$ make
```

More details on the hocus-pocus: https://makefiletutorial.com/